# How can I make my Panel wrap text and increase in height instead of width when contained in a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

[FINAL EDIT]

Ok folks.

I don't know why it does not work in my chat program... but I managed to fix the SSCCE.. with the scrollable implementation it works now. Thank you all!

Code:

```
package de.sky.cjat;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MyKskb {
    
    private int row;
    
    class SomethingPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public SomethingPanel(LayoutManager manager){
            super(manager);
        }
        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(){
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction){
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight(){
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth(){
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    public MyKskb(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
//      final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final SomethingPanel content = new SomethingPanel(new GridBagLayout());

//      final JPanel empty = new JPanel();
//      empty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
//      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//      content.add(empty, gbc);
        content.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "§");
        content.getActionMap().put("§", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2));
                p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                gbc.weightx = 1.0;
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = row++;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                
//              content.remove(empty);
//              gbc.gridy = row;
//              gbc.weighty = 1.0;
//              content.add(empty, gbc);
            
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea(
                        Math.random() > 0.5 ? 
                        "ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC" : 
                        "FFFFFFFFFFFFABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC");
                text.setLineWrap(true);
                p.add(text);
                content.add(p, gbc);
                content.revalidate();
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(scrollPane);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        new MyKskb();
    }
}
```

[END]

[QUESTION]

I'm writing a Chat Program, and the layout looks like this:

[image]

The Panel with the messages has a GridBagLayout and is wrapped in a JScrollPane.

The problem is, if the message is too long, the message panel stretches and gets too big:

[image]

So what I want to achieve, is to limit the size of the panel, which is wrapped in the JScrollPane - I want the gray panels with the message text to increase their height, if the text gets longer, not wider. I.e. wrap the text, without increasing the panel width.

Is there a way to achieve this with the grid bag layout, or am I missing something? Or should I use another layout manager?

Edit: The full Hierarchy:

```
JScrollPane
    JPanel (gbl)
        JPanel (custom painting)
            JComponent (JLabel but it can vary)
        JPanel (custom painting)
            JComponent (JLabel but it can vary)
        JPanel (custom painting)
            JComponent (JLabel but it can vary)
        ....
```

edit: I tried to implement Scrollable like this:

```
@Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(){
        return new Dimension(100, getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction){
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight(){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth(){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction){
        return 1;
    }
```

but the same thing happens if the text gets too long... I don't know what `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` should return, but also `getSize()` didn't work...

EDIT: here is a SSCCE, it shows the basic structure of my GUI: (press enter to add new component)

```
package de.sky.cjat;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Kskb {
    
    private int row;
    
    public Kskb(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JPanel empty = new JPanel();
        empty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        content.add(empty, gbc);
        content.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "§");
        content.getActionMap().put("§", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                JLabel text = new JLabel("ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC");
                p.add(text);
                
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                gbc.weightx = 1.0;
                gbc.gridy = row++;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
                
                content.add(p, gbc);
                
                content.remove(empty);
                gbc.gridy = row;
                gbc.weighty = 1.0;
                content.add(empty, gbc);
                
                content.revalidate();
            }
        });
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(scrollPane);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        new Kskb();
    }
}
```

Comment: What type of Component contains the messages (eg is being added to the panel containing the GridBagLayout)? JLabel? JPanel with custom painting?

Comment: Do you want the text to line wrap dynamically? If I resize the window so that more or less text can fit in a single line, should the lines be recalculated immediately?

Comment: yep, that would be my aim..

Comment: I will post an answer shortly, but in the meantime you have to realize that you will have to deal with space issues somehow. If I make the frame less wide and get multiple lines as you want, and then make the frame less tall, eventually you will not have enough space for all the text. How do you want to deal with that?

Comment: do you insinuate that i have to write my own layout manager?...

I thought about a css-like behavior.. like this: https://jsfiddle.net/u26gu2d3/

Comment: Not at all! See my answer and you'll see what I mean when you have many entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @durandal's advice, the problem is the JLabel. A JLabel does not wrap text. So you need to use a different component. Here is your code modified with a JTextArea:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Kskb {

    private int row;

    public Kskb()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
//        final JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final ScrollablePanel content = new ScrollablePanel(new GridBagLayout());
        content.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
        final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        content.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "");
        content.getActionMap().put("", new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JPanel p = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
                p.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
                p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
                text.append("ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCA BCABCABCABCABCABCABCAB CABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC");
                text.setLineWrap( true );
                p.add(text);

                gbc.gridy = row++;
                content.add(p, gbc);
                content.revalidate();
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(content);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(scrollPane);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        new Kskb();
    }
}
```

The key is the `Scrollable` implementation which forces the panels width to be adjusted ad the frame is adjusted. This code uses the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/), which is just a reusable implementation of the `Scrollable` interface that you can configure with methods instead of creating a new class and overriding the methods.

Comment: hey. thank you for the answer. That works pretty well actually. But could you explain, how this scrollablepanel works? I would like to implement the same my self, just for experience...

Comment: so, how should i implement the scrollable interface so it works like this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an effect of the interaction between JScrollPane and its content. A scroll pane will (by default) provide as much space as the contents desires.

So in that sense, the layout is working perfectly.

To give the component shown in a scroll pane actually control of the size of the container it shows, the contained component can implement the interface `javax.swing.Scrollable`.

Try something like this:

```
public class MyVerticalPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    // other method and implementation
}
```

More documentation is available here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollable

Comment: @T_01 You can just return getPreferredSize() from getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(). The ViewPort layout manager will correct the witdh automatically as long as getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() returns true. If that *doesn't* work, your nested components probably do *not properly adhere* to the layout managers commands (maybe they return unsuitable dimensions in getMinimunSize()). Try without the ScrollPane, if they still exceed the window, the components themselves need fixing.

Comment: 1+, the Scrollable interface is important. The solution also needs a component that can wrap to take advantage of the changing widths. It wasn't apparent from the original question how the OP was displaying the text.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get something working that is along the lines of what you want:

```
public class Chatter extends JFrame {

    JTextField enterTextField = new JTextField("This is a lot of text it's way too loooooooooooooooong to fit in one line but it is used to check for wrapping by words and characters some more text just for fun no punctuation");
    JPanel historyPanel = new JPanel();

    public Chatter() {

        enterTextField.addActionListener(new enterTextActionListener());

        historyPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(historyPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(historyPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        getContentPane().add(enterTextField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class enterTextActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(enterTextField.getText());
            textArea.setLineWrap(true);
            textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 5));
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(textArea.getPreferredSize());   

            historyPanel.add(scrollPane);
            historyPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,10)));
            historyPanel.revalidate();
//          enterTextField.setText(""); // Commented out for convenience while testing.
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Chatter();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

I use `JTextArea`s to display the text since it has text wrapping support. Each text area is inside a `JScrollPane` in order to allow vertical scrolling as a last resort if there is not enough space to display the text.

**Notes:**

- I used a `JTextField` as the input method for text, you can use a multiline text component instead.

  - The initial text is just for testing.
  - The text is not cleared with every entry for testing (see the commented line in the code).
- I used `BoxLayout` for the panel which holds the text messages because it seemed simpler and more natural. `GridBagLayout` could surely be used instead.
- I set `setWrapStyleWord(true)` because it's probably the right behavior to wrap by words. If you want to wrap by characters then delete this line.
- I added a border and spaces for testing. Use whatever styling you want instead.

Comment: thank you, +1 for your help, but this solution does'nt look really good. I dont want to scroll inside of the textareas. That is ugly...

Comment: It can be improved if you specify what you want to get exactly, but if you found a solution then it's fine.

Comment: @T_01 I already know of the `Scrollable` solution, I was providing an alternative since someone already posted that idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

```
Jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x size, y size));
Jframe.add(Jpanel);
```

I think most layout managers work better with setPreferredSize than setSize.

Comment: i don't use absolute sizes. they have to be calculated by the layout managers, that's what they are for..

Comment: You could try setting width as a percentage of the frame width, or frame width - some buffer.

Comment: then i had to change it every time the frame resizes. that would'nt be a nice solution. and i cannot set the y size, because the panel has to grow on the y axis if the content gets too big